# How do I share an object with another user using Parse with iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, parse-platform

I have dug through a few of the tutorials at parse.com and I don't have a problem with users creating objects and storing them in Parse.

What I don't know how to do is passing an object to another user. So, for example, if I have users with their own to do lists, and a friend wants to add to another users' to do list, how would I go about doing that? So one user would create the object:

```
PFObject *task = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"ToDo"];
[task setObject:@"Do the dishes" forKey:@"userName"];
[task save];
```

But I'd like this user to pass the task to a friend of theirs, so when their friend launches the app, they see the task added to their list.

I'm using the Facebook SDK as well, so if there's something there that could help, I could use that.

I haven't used Core Data before, so I was hoping to handle a lot of the backend work with parse so I could avoid the learning curve for the time being.

Thanks for all the help

I'd like to add that I'm not necessarily looking for an "answer". I just haven't done anything like this before so, I wouldn't know where to look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use user pointers & ACLs for this.

```
// assume PFUser *assigned 
PFACL *acl = [PFACL ACLWithUser:PFUser.currentUser];
[acl setReadAccess:YES forUser:assigned];
PFObject *todo = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Todo"];
todo[@"task"] = @"Wash dishes";
todo[@"user"] = assigned;
todo.ACL = acl;
[todo saveInBackground];
```

Now, you can see all TODOs with

```
[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Todo"];
```

You can see all queries which are assigned to you with

```
[query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:PFUser.currentUser];
```

And only the creator of a TODO can edit it.

Comment: If I want to assigned TODO for several users its possible ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a many to many relationship here : a user can own many todo objects and a todo object can be own by many users.

This kind of approach can be handle with `PFRelation` object. Take a look at the official blog post here : http://blog.parse.com/2012/05/17/new-many-to-many/

Comment: That could work. The only thing is, the initial user who makes the todo item sends it to his/her friend. That to do item is now their friends, and only visible by their friend. But, I'd also make it read only, so that friend cannot 'delete' todo tasks that are sent to them. I'll take a look at the PFRelation object though! Thanks!

Comment: If you want to control deletion, you can also manually block it using the beforeDelete cloud code trigger. Chck out the blog post at http://blog.parse.com/2013/08/22/deleting-objects/

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't handle it as a many to many relationship in this case.

The person who creates the todo object should be the only owner. You can add an attribute to the todo object and it's type can be an array. The array can then keep track of who it's shared with. If someone it's shared with deleted it you can then just remove them from the array or if the owner deletes it the object can just be deleted.